Error loading transaction history when UI querying cgw querying transaction service
Describe the bug
Error loading transaction history on UI (Refer to below screenshot)
txs-service-web log:
2024-08-14 01:47:51,564 MT::GET::api/v1/about/singletons/::4::200::/api/v1/about/singletons/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,639 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/balances/::14::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/balances/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,705 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/::136::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,744 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/transfers/::17::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/transfers/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,744 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/multisig-transactions/::18::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/multisig-transactions/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,746 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/transfers/::32::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/transfers/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,748 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/multisig-transactions/::31::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/multisig-transactions/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,751 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/messages/::10::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/messages/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,752 MT::GET::api/v1/contracts/<str:address>/::5::404::/api/v1/contracts/0x29fcB43b46531BcA003ddC8FCB67FFE91900C762/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,755 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/module-transactions/::20::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/module-transactions/
2024-08-14 01:47:51,759 MT::GET::api/v1/contracts/<str:address>/::17::404::/api/v1/contracts/0xfd0732Dc9E303f09fCEf3a7388Ad10A83459Ec99/
2024-08-14 01:48:00,884 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/multisig-transactions/::12::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/multisig-transactions/
2024-08-14 01:48:00,934 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/all-transactions/::3::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/all-transactions/
2024-08-14 01:48:00,946 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/messages/::4::200::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/messages/
2024-08-14 01:48:00,965 [ERROR] [MainProcess] Internal Server Error: /api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/creation/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 48, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 188, in _view_wrapper
    result = _process_exception(request, e)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 186, in _view_wrapper
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/views.py", line 970, in get
    safe_creation_info = SafeServiceProvider().get_safe_creation_info(address)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/services/safe_service.py", line 111, in get_safe_creation_info
    parent_internal_tx = self._get_parent_internal_tx(creation_internal_tx)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/safe_transaction_service/history/services/safe_service.py", line 287, in _get_parent_internal_tx
    previous_trace = self.ethereum_tracing_client.tracing.get_previous_trace(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gnosis/eth/ethereum_client.py", line 993, in get_previous_trace
    traces = reversed(self.trace_transaction(tx_hash))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gnosis/eth/ethereum_client.py", line 1067, in trace_transaction
    return self.slow_w3.tracing.trace_transaction(tx_hash)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 75, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 330, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 279, in formatted_response
    raise MethodUnavailable(
web3.exceptions.MethodUnavailable: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'the method trace_transaction does not exist/is not available'}
2024-08-14 01:48:00,996 MT::GET::api/v1/safes/<str:address>/creation/::46::500::/api/v1/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/creation/

CGW log:
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":{"chain_id":"530","client_ip":"172.30.187.89","detail":"An error occurred","method":"GET","origin":null,"path":"/v1/chains/530/safes/0x92d7986F80c3179561166D83ee2A2B3d0B35c7A8/transactions/history?timezone_offset=28800000&trusted=false","response_time_ms":70.46555100381374,"route":"/v1/chains/:chainId/safes/:safeAddress/transactions/history","safe_app_user_agent":null,"status_code":500},"request_id":"5818ab3b-b5cb-455d-a9b2-e3674d0e7a80","timestamp":"2024-08-14T01:48:00.998Z","version":"v1.53.0"}

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Setup using https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/
Create safe wallet UI
Go to dashboard -> transaction history

Expected behavior
It should display the transaction history
Environment (please complete the following information):

Production
Chain: fxcore mainnet and testnet
Chrome
Version: latest on all components

Additional context

Our RPC does not have trace namespace
Only debug namespace is available e.g. debug_traceTransaction

You will most likely receive these errors because you configured the transaction service to use traces for indexing the Safes, but your RPC node does not support them.
You can try to index the Safes using events. This would involve the following steps.
Reconfigure your .env file
You can use this example configuration as a reference.

Don't configure tracing in your .env file. So omit setting the ETHEREUM_TRACING_NODE_URL env var.
Configure the Ethereum node by setting the ETHEREUM_NODE_URL env var.

Use the SafeL2 Versions of Safe that emit events
The L1 Version does not emit events to save gas.

Configure Transaction Service to index the SafeL2 MasterCopy and mark it as L2.



In config service, check L2.



Configure the recommended version as 1.3.0.


Please be aware that this will require more gas and should be used on chains where gas is not too expensive.
Let us know if this solves your problem (and mark the question as answered) or if you encounter further issues.

ok it works after disable the tracing node

Perfect, well done! Let us know if you have further issues.

if you don't mind, I have another issue under here
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/165549/error-getting-token-prices
