Error getting token prices
cgw-web logs
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5fd55a1b9fc24967c4db09c513c3ba0dfa7ff687 price from provider ","request_id":"d5163224-b2ec-479e-8b8b-d476151ea427","timestamp":"2024-08-22T08:52:32.360Z","version":"v1.53.0"}
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5fd55a1b9fc24967c4db09c513c3ba0dfa7ff687 price from provider ","request_id":"f9368fe0-28a1-4324-ab91-e4a419d0fc5a","timestamp":"2024-08-22T08:52:46.862Z","version":"v1.53.0"}
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5fd55a1b9fc24967c4db09c513c3ba0dfa7ff687 price from provider ","request_id":"313fb22f-fc41-462f-9191-6c330c0a7461","timestamp":"2024-08-22T08:53:01.984Z","version":"v1.53.0"}
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5777b1a0e57c239b2affbc4448dc92378204224d price from provider ","request_id":"8b9cd3c9-3ae1-44ca-8cd1-3480ef8df8a7","timestamp":"2024-08-22T08:54:10.906Z","version":"v1.53.0"}
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5777b1a0e57c239b2affbc4448dc92378204224d price from provider ","request_id":"82b05d88-68a1-4be2-9921-05c686ef31a0","timestamp":"2024-08-22T08:54:26.275Z","version":"v1.53.0"}
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5777b1a0e57c239b2affbc4448dc92378204224d price from provider ","request_id":"fca045ec-669d-4b03-9797-8d86d24afa67","timestamp":"2024-08-22T08:56:51.217Z","version":"v1.53.0"}
{"build_number":"234a559","level":"error","message":"Error getting token prices: Error: Error getting 0x5777b1a0e57c239b2affbc4448dc92378204224d price from provider ","request_id":"aca1cc75-ff5d-468d-8e0d-4bf3bb134897","timestamp":"2024-08-27T07:31:30.884Z","version":"v1.53.0"}

how to fix it?
did i miss out any config on the cfg?

our setup is using the https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure with a lot of modification

Thanks for your question, and sorry for the delay. We actively monitor questions asked with the safe-core tag, so this slipped our attention.
Here is a cross-post of the reply you received to your question in our Github repo:
First, you query the Coingecko API (https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/asset_platforms) to receive data about your chain.
{
 "id": "function-x",
 "chain_identifier": 530,
 "name": "Function X",
 "shortname": "",
 "native_coin_id": "fx-coin"
},

Then you use this data in the Config Service Chain configuration following. native_coin_id (in the Coingecko response) as Prices provider native coin (in the Config Service Chain configuration). And also id (in the Coingecko response) as Prices provider chain name (in the Config Service Chain configuration).
In the case of fxChain, this would mean:
Prices provider native coin: fx-coin
Prices provider chain name: function-x

If this answers your question, please mark it as answered. If not, please leave us a comment with additional information so we can help you out further.

ok actually it works now for the native coin, how about all our other tokens?
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-config-service/issues/1217#issuecomment-2323659010

Let me check internally.

So, you only have to configure the native token in the proposed way. For all other tokens the address is enough. You have to make sure that Coingecko lists these tokens.
